Git safe restore to old commit and return to latest
I have question related to git
I need to do following :

Restore repository to state as it was on some specific old commit
Make branch from this state and add some changes to the branch
Return to master and restore to latest state

What is correct and safe way to do so ? I think about first option
git revert <mycommit_name> 

or
git reset --soft <mycommit_name>

Thanks in advance

It's unclear what you want to do here. Words like "restore" and commands like "revert" imply you want to throw out existing work. But I think you just want to do some new work based off an old commit. A concrete example might help.

I think you're asking how you do work based off an older version.
For example, you have commits like so...
* C [master] - added the cool thing
|
* B - fixed that annoying bug
|
* A - did that mundane task

You can see a view of your repository like this with git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline.
Now, for whatever reason, you want to do work off commit B. Make a branch from commit B. A branch is nothing more than a label on a commit. git-branch optionally takes a starting point for the new branch.
$ git branch B_branch B

* C [master] - added the cool thing
|
* B [B_branch] - fixed that annoying bug
|
* A - did that mundane task

Now you have B_branch at commit B. Switch to that branch and make some commits. They will be on top of B. master will be unaffected.
$ git switch B_branch
...work work work...
$ git commit -m 'B commit 1'
...work work work...
$ git commit -m 'B commit 2'

* E [B_branch] - B commit 2
|
* D - B commit 1
|
|  * C [master] - added the cool thing
| /
* B - fixed that annoying bug
|
* A - did that mundane task

And when you're done, switch back to master. git switch master.

Hi @Schwern . What you described here seems like to what I need - I will try and update . Thanks anyway for quick reply

Update : Checked - that is what I needed . Thanks a lot
